# Web Scraping through 48,000 url pages for 1 day and a half and still going. Is that normal?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've collected 48,000 url pages and I put them in a list. My goal is to extract 8 pieces of data using BeautifulSoup and appending each data point to an empty list from this list of urls.

Before I ran the for loop below I tested the extraction on 3 urls from the list and it worked perfectly fine.

I know the code works but I am questioning the amount of time it is taking to complete the web scrape of 48,000 url pages since my code has been running for a day and a half already. This is making me question my code or that I created the code inefficiently.

Can someone please review my code and provide any suggestions or ideas on how to make the code run faster?

Thanks in advance!

```
title_list = []
price_list = []
descrip_list = []
grape_variety_list = []
region_list = []
region_list2 = []
wine_state_list = []
wine_country_list = []

with requests.Session() as session:
    for link in grape_review_links_list:
        response2 = session.get(link, headers=headers)
        wine_html = response2.text
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(wine_html, 'html.parser')

        wine_title = soup2.find('span', class_='rating').findNext('h1').text
        title_list.append(wine_title)

        wine_price = soup2.find(text='Buy Now').findPrevious('span').text.split(',')[0]
        price_list.append(wine_price)

        wine_descrip = soup2.find('p', class_='description').find(text=True, recursive=False)
        descrip_list.append(wine_descrip)

        wine_grape = soup2.find(text='Buy Now').findNext('a').text
        grape_variety_list.append(wine_grape)

        wine_region = soup2.find(text='Appellation').findNext('a').text
        region_list.append(wine_region)

        wine_region2 = soup2.find(text='Appellation').findNext('a').findNext('a').text
        region_list2.append(wine_region2)

        wine_state = soup2.find(text='Appellation').findNext('a').findNext('a').findNext('a').text
        wine_state_list.append(wine_state)

        wine_country = soup2.find(text='Appellation').findNext('a').findNext('a').findNext('a').findNext('a').text
        wine_country_list.append(wine_country)
```

Comment: all the soup2.find(text='Appellation').findNext('a')...repeated....findNext('a').text would likely work faster without the .text, saving the current position and using it both to get the text and then the next 'a'. And findall 'a' may also have been better, and can be limited : soup2.find_all("a", limit=4) cf https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all which would give you the 4 tags in one call

Comment: Depending on the size of the pages and the speed of your connection... it doesn't seem unreasonable to me... are all the links you've got for the same domain?

Comment: @B.Go thank you for your suggestion. I will try that next time and review the link you provided.

Comment: @JonClements the links are all from the same domain.  This is my first time doing some real web scraping so it caused me to have doubt that the code is nearly running for two days.  I don't want to strain my computer resources either. I will continue to have faith and let it run. Hopefully by tomorrow it's done.

Comment: Do stuff like add outputs, batch the job, add some tests, etc, until you are not needing faith :)

Comment: @H.Hernandez I'd recommend having a look at https://scrapy.org/ if you're doing any kind of serious scraping - that can run requests in parallel, will produce an ongoing log so you can see how many items you've got and how many pages have been crawled etc... and you can even stop/resume it etc etc...

Comment: @Andrew - when you say add outputs, do you mean print statments? When you say batch the job, do you mean to create separate for loops for each data point?

Comment: @JonClements - Wow! Scrapy sounds great!. I will definitely review the link you provide. Thank you for your insight!

Comment: @H.Hernandez it's a little bit of a mind change than using requests and beautifulsoup as in you don't really worry about the requests and you generally have to use css selectors/xpath, but the [tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) is friendly enough

Comment: Lxml is also often much faster than BS